# how to avoid Async callouts inside trigger

Tags: trigger, asynchronous

i have below trigger. How to separate callouts out of for loop.

```
trigger userAttach on Attachment (after insert,before insert) {
    for(Attachment att: [select Id, Name, body, contenttype, Parent.Id, Parent.Type from Attachment where id = : trigger.new]){
        if(att.Parent.Type == 'Care_Provider__c' && att.body!=null 
            && (att.contenttype=='image/jpeg' || att.contenttype=='image/png' || att.contenttype=='image/jpg')){
            Home_user.rent_callout(att.id);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add the id of the attachment to the set of id and bulkify the future method to accept set

```
trigger userAttach on Attachment (after insert,before insert) {
set<id> attIdSet = new set<id>();
    for(Attachment att: [select Id, Name, body, contenttype, Parent.Id, Parent.Type from Attachment where id = : trigger.new]){
        if(att.Parent.Type == 'Care_Provider__c' && att.body!=null 
            && (att.contenttype=='image/jpeg' || att.contenttype=='image/png' || att.contenttype=='image/jpg')){
           attIdSet.add(att.id);
        }
    }

//call the future method here assuming you have bulkified the asynchronous method
Home_user.rent_callout(attIdSet);
}
```

Hope this helps!!